# How does scanf recognize the input(string) as integer?

Tags: c, scanf

I'm wondering how scanf in C recognizess the input,which is a string, as intger when the conversion specifier is `%d` For example,

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int x;
    scanf("%d",&x);
    printf("%d \n",x);
}
```

When my input is 123456, how does scanf interpret this string as an integer? 
Also, what's the difference between recognizing the input string when the conversion specifiers in scanf are `%hd` and `%d`?

Comment: ... it reads the `1` sees that it is a digit with value `1`, goes ahead sees a `2` which is an other digit of value `2` and does `1*10+2 = 12`,then continues until the `6` and after that symbol it finds a space/newline/whatever which is not a digit and understand that the number finished.

Comment: @Bakuriu How is the letter '1' read as value 1? Can you tell me the process in more detail?

Comment: How? A stupid way of doing it is: `char letter = /* get one character input */; int value; switch letter {case '1': value=1;}`. If you are using ASCII then you have the guarantee that digits `0` to `9` are consecutive characters and so you can convert a digit using `int value = digit - '0';` Note it's not `- 0` which would do nothing is `- '0'` so you are subtracting the character code for the character `0`.

Comment: @Bakuriu Then if an input is 123456, then is each character ('1','2'...'6') 8 bit?

Comment: Did you have a look at an implementation of `scanf`? What **specifically** did you not understand and not already asked here or elsewhere?

Comment: Okay, I believe you are missing the fundamental concepts of what is a string, what is a number etc. Without these concepts it's impossible to uderstand how `scanf` works. Take a C manual and study it.

Comment: @jwqwerty: can you please accept one of the answers, so we can really close this question?

Answer (score 2):

`scanf` reads data from stdin and stores them according to the parameter format into the locations pointed by the additional arguments. So when you write %d for the fotmat the input it interpreted as integer.

`%d` stands for integer (e.g. 4 bytes for most 32 bit systems)

`%hd` stands for short integer (half the size of integer)

Comment: Can you tell me the process how the letter is read as integer in more detail?

Comment: the sizes of `short` and `int` are system dependent.

Comment: perhaps it help you to look at the funtion `sprintf` which directly converts a string according to a desired parameter format

Answer (score 2):

`scanf()` scans the format string and reads bytes from `stdin` to try and match expected sequences specified in the format string.  A format of `%d` commands `scanf()` to read bytes and compute the value of an `int` from the decimal representation. For this, its follows the steps:

- first read and discard any bytes that match `isspace()`: `' '`, `'\t'`, `'\r'`, `'\n'`, `'\v'`, `'\f'` and possibly some other values.
- then read an optional sign: `-` or `+`. set the initial value to `0`.
- then repeatedly read bytes that correspond to digits: `0` to `9`. Compute the value represented by these digits: for each digit, mutiply the value computed so far and add the value of the digit, `c - '0'` for ASCII.
- stop whenever the byte read is not a digit, and push this byte back into `stdin` with `ungetc(c, stdin);`

If no digits have been seen, stop the scanning process and return the number of formats correctly stored so far (in case there are multiple formats in the `scanf` format string) or `EOF` in case of complete mismatch.

If at least one digit was seen, apply the optional negative sign to the computed value and store the result to the pointer passed as an extra argument to `scanf()`.  If the format was `%hd`, this pointer is a `short *`, so the value will be converted into a `short` before storing.

Continue scanning the format string until its end.